# cannot push_back into a referenced vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector

ok so I have a thread that is meant to add to a vector of players but whenever I call the push_back function I get a memory access violations, I've taken out all other code where the vector is being used outside of this thread.

I can read the size of the vector before this happens but I just cannot push_back into it.

the vector looks like this:

```
std::vector<A_Player> &clientsRef;
```

adn the thread that it is in is:

```
void NetworkManager::TCPAcceptClient(){
std::cout << "Waiting to accept that client that pinged us" << std::endl;
fd_set fd;
timeval tv;
FD_ZERO(&fd);
FD_SET(TCPListenSocket, &fd);

tv.tv_sec = 5;//seconds
tv.tv_usec = 0;//miliseconds

A_Player thePlayer;
thePlayer.sock = SOCKET_ERROR;

if (select(0, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0){ //using select to allow a timeout if the client fails to connect
    if (thePlayer.sock == SOCKET_ERROR){
        thePlayer.sock = accept(TCPListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    }

    thePlayer.playerNumber = clientsRef.size() + 1;
    thePlayer.isJumping = false;
    thePlayer.X = 0;
    thePlayer.Y = 0;
    thePlayer.Z = 0;
    clientsRef.push_back(thePlayer);

    clientHandler = std::thread(&NetworkManager::ClientRecieve, this);
    clientHandler.detach();
}
else{
    std::cout << "Client connection timed out!!!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

}

Can anyone give me some insight into why this doesn't work?

Kind regards

Comment: How is this reference initialized (std::vector<A_Player> &clientsRef is a reference and must be initialized)?

Comment: through the constructor

Comment: No, a reference has no constructor. Have a look at the `&` sign. That makes clientsRef a reference and a compiler should complain about a line like `std::vector<A_Player> &clientsRef;`, because clientsRef is not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that referencing wouldn't work for the problem I had and I converted it to a pointer system which worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your `clientsRef` reference is referencing a destroyed local vector. Take a look at the code where you set the reference.